# Issue with Lazy Loading and Path matching

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

```
    // App Routes
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '',                 redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch:'full' },
    { path: 'account',          loadChildren: './app/account/account.module#AccountModule' },
    { path: 'enterprise',       loadChildren: './app/company/company.module#CompanyModule' },
    { path: 'home',             component: DashboardComponent,     canActivate:[SessionGuard]   },
    { path: 'profile',          component: ProfileComponent,  canActivate:[SessionGuard]   },
    { path: 'user/:username',   component: UserComponent,     canActivate:[SessionGuard]   },    
    { path: '**',               component: ErrorComponent }
];
// Account Routes
export const ACCOUNT_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AccountComponent,
        outlet: 'account',
        children: [
            { path: 'forgot', component: ForgotComponent},
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
            { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
        ]
    }
];

// Company Routes
export const COMPANY_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'compnay',
        component: CompanyComponent,
        outlet: 'account',
        children: [
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
            { path: 'careers', component: CareersComponent},
        ]
    }
];
```

I am having an issue with routing using Lazy Loaded Modules. Error is printing out like this :

> core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'account/login' Error: Cannot match any
>   routes. URL Segment: 'account/login'

My modules reflect correctly...

```
// App Module
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ], 
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    CompanyModule,
    AccountModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {
       useHash: Boolean(history.pushState) === false,
       preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    SessionGuard,
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}

// Account Lazy Module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(ACCOUNT_ROUTES)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AccountComponent,
        ...
    ],    
    bootstrap: [AccountComponent]
})
export class CompanyModule {}

// Company Lazy Module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(COMPANY_ROUTES)
    ],
    declarations: [
        CompanyComponent,
        ...
    ],    
    bootstrap: [CompanyComponent]
})
export class CompanyModule {}
```

I am also using Router Outlet for viewing the routes on each module.

```
// app level
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

// account level
<router-outlet name="account"></router-outlet>

// company level
<router-outlet name="company"></router-outlet>
```

If anyone can decipher this ... that would be a huge help... I've been at this for hours now, and every change I make produces the same output.

Comment: how you are redirecting?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Assuming you are asking about the SessionGuard I'm using `this._router.navigate(['/account/login']);` when the user is not logged in.

Comment: But it doesn't matter if I redirect/navigate or just directly hit the URL ... it still returns that the path doesn't exist. I had to comment out the '**' path to get the error, otherwise it just redirects to the error component.

Comment: did you check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
this._router.navigate(['account', 'login'])
```

or navigatebyURL

```
this_router.navigateByUrl('/account/login')
```

Comment: Like I stated before, it doesn't matter how I navigate to the URL.